# Is there any chance I can detect the Wifi band connected with my iPhone, like 802.11ac, in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Forget the grammar rules in my question since english is not my mother tongue;

I want to detect my current Wifi hotspot, if it is in 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz in iOS environment，anyone got the idea or possibility？ Here is my code below:

```
 NSString *wifiName = nil;
CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
if (myArray != nil) {
    CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
    if (myDict != nil) {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)CFBridgingRelease(myDict);
        wifiName = [dict valueForKey:@"SSID"];
    }
}
return wifiName;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know you cant do this with native APIs. But there is a private API [Stumbler](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler) for working with wifi in a more advanced way.

**[Warning]:** If You Use Private APIs You Will Not Be Able To Distribute Your App through Appstore.

Comment: I dropped this feature function cause my App has to distribute by App Store, thank you also.